# Permission access of the table , view and function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a View A that will select data from view B . I only want an user ,say Peter ,  to have  read-only access on view A but cannot select from the view B . So I grant him only have the `SELECT` right on View A and `REFERENCES` right on View B . It work very nice.

Now ,  I have a Function A that will select  data from a Table B , and I want Peter can execute  Function A but cannot select data from the table  B. So , I do the same thing which  grants Peter only have the `EXECUTE` right on Function A  and `REFERENCES` right on Table B  . But , it cannot work and an error message `"ERROR: permission denied for relation TableB"` is thrown when peter executes Function A. How come it does not work  this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for [security definer](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createfunction.html).

As an aside, be wary of the [leaky view problem](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2009-10/msg01346.php). It isn't entirely fixed yet.

Comment: Thanks Denis . security definer is what I am looking for .Do you think the view also have the same security definer feature ? I think it does not as I cannot find anything about security definer on view , right?

Comment: You've got view security right. Security definer is for functions.